# Add a column from another object to an existing listview

Tags: django, python-2.7, listview, django-1.3

I have an existing listview and I want to add a new column(contactDate) from another object which will be soratble. I want to sort my LeftListView by the contact_date of the Action each Left record contains.
my objects are:

```
class Left(models.Model):
   ref = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
   customer = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   days = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   business_classification = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s in %s (%d days)' % (
        self.customer,
        self.days_in_delay
    )
class Action(models.Model):
  left = models.ForeignKey(Left, related_name='actions')
  personal_use = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='actions')
  phone_calls = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  contact_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.description
```

My listview is as above:

```
class LeftListView(ListView):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(LeftListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def get_queryset(self):
    for_date = self.kwargs.get('date', datetime.date.today())
    week_start, week_end = find_week_start_end(for_date=for_date)
    qs_others = Left.objects.filter(created__startswith=str(for_date))  
    qs= qs_others #| qs_cc
    reqGET = self.request.GET

@property
def querystring(self):
    params = dict(self.request.GET.items())
    for k, v in params.items():
        if not all(v):
            params.pop(k)
    has_page = params.pop('page', False)
    return '?%s' % urlencode(params)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(LeftListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx['querystring'] = self.querystring
    for_date = self.kwargs.get('date')
    if for_date is not None:
        ctx['for_date'] = for_date
    ctx.update(search_ranges)
    ctx['filter_form'] = LeftFilterForm(self.request.GET or None,
        initial=search_ranges)
    ctx['contact_date'] = Action.objects.filter(contact_date=for_date).filter(left_ref=left.ref)

    return ctx
```

The result should somehow be as below:

```
No.    REF     Customer     Amount    Created Date         Days      Contact Day


1.   AB-9     Name Surname   amount    Dec 30, 2018        68        Dec 3, 2018 
2.   AB-5010  Name7 Surname7  amount    Mar 20, 2018       80            
3.   AB-78    Nametest Surnametest   amount  Dec 18, 2018   6
4.   AB-73019  Name5 Surname5   amount   Jul 08, 2018      13        Dec 3, 2018
```

As a newbie in python I haven't found a good example that fits my solution till now.
Any orientation is well-appreciated.

Comment: The FK is from Action to Left, so there are multiple Actions for each Left. Which one do you want to order by? You will need to post your view. Also note that Django 1.3 is seven years old and *totally* insecure, you must upgrade immediately.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added my listview, but I'm not sure about it. I want to  sort by contact_date. I know 1.3 is a very old version but I need to do this immediate request before I upgrade the environment.

Comment: @BernhardBallant I saw you are familiar with django 1.3. Can you give me a hand, pls?

Comment: Describe what you want in the end. Not "another column" - what do you want to do with it? Are you sure you realize what 1:M relation is? Single `Left` and bunch of `Action`s.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I want to display in a gridview: ref, customer,days, business_classification  from Left and add the contact_date from Action. Each Left has a unique ref, which contains different actions with different contact_date and I want to display, let's say, refs which has contact_date=today.I don't know if I have made myself clear at all?

Comment: Do you mean **tree**view?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I guess not. I mean, it will display these refs in a gridview/html-table and to display action-contact_date of these refs if contact_date =Today. Only one action per ref could happen to have contact_date =today.So it won't be displayed in a treeview but in a single row/ref

Comment: Please add sample data (like json or whatever) and desired output (draw it in Paint or write a preformatted text) to your question.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Added a formatted text-table at the end of the question, just for illustration. If it has a contact_date=today it will display it. Else don't display it.